# How to bind the Document property to FlowDocumentScrollViewer from code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I bind the Document property to FlowDocumentScrollViewer, like here in XAML:

```xml
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer Document="{Binding ElementName=Element, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource TextToFlowDocumentConverter}}"/>
```

but in code behind?

Comment: Why would you want to do that on code behind, and to which property do you want to bind it? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this completely solves what you're trying to do, but if you give the `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` a name in the XAML, like so:

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer Name="FlowDocViewer" />
```

You can set the `Document` property in the code-behind.

Like so:

```
 public MyWindow() // constructor, in case this is confusing
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FlowDocViewer.Document = SomeDocumentObject;
    }
```

Comment: @flakerZ it sounds like Binding with a `FlowDocument` is a little bit trickier (I haven't used it before, so I had to dig around). There's a recommendation here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3dc81264-984d-4ffa-81c5-b9bb7034cabc/document-belongs-to-another-flowdocumentscrollviewer-already?forum=wpf to use the `Loaded` and `Unloaded` events on the `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` to set the binding. Is that feasible for you?